# Ubuntu Server 14.04 on old MacPro

Tags: server, uefi, 14.04

there is a way to run Ubuntu Server 14.04 on an old MacPro with EFI 32Bit?
There is support in ubuntu 14.04 for 32 bit EFI?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your two questions: Yes and no, respectively.

Ubuntu has long supported installation on Macs in BIOS mode. Most users opt to use the discontinued rEFIt or its updated fork, [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to manage such installations, although it can be done in other ways, too.

Ubuntu does not support installation in EFI mode on 32-bit computers; however, there are 32-bit builds of GRUB in Ubuntu, and other tools (including rEFInd) can boot Ubuntu in EFI mode on 32-bit Macs. See, for instance, my [Web page on how to set this up,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) although that's a bit old. Also, be aware that I've had problems with EFI-mode booting Ubuntu 14.04 in EFI mode, whereas 12.04.1 works much better. I suspect that some kernel compile options have changed in a way that negatively impacts EFI-mode booting, but I haven't yet investigated this in detail.